# where to find tutorial for studying how to use ?, {, \ search query like {searchboxquery?}

Tags: enterprise-search, sharepoint-search

Where to find tutorial for studying how to use ?, {, \ in search query like {searchboxquery?} in SharePoint 2013

Comment: Have a look at https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj683123.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your reply Bunzab. But this still does not give me what happen when I use ? \  :(

Comment: Do you know what the ? means in a URL?

Comment: Yes, Danny. Thanks. One of my solution to get result only from current site is \\{SearchBoxQuery?} Path:https://my site path. And another query text to search only from my list title goes like this :  {?Title:{searchTerms}}. So, in these two solutions the use of "?" are different. And the usage of "\\" in the first solution. These both solutions works but didnt get how actually works.

Comment: Using {? searchTerms} means if the searchquery variable is empty everything between the braces will be omitted from the query. I have not used nor do I know what the double backslashes are used for...

Answer (score 1):

The curly brace wraps your terms, the question mark removes the query if the contents is null, the backslash is an escape character.

Follow this terrific series: [SharePoint Search Queries Explained](http://www.techmikael.com/2014/03/sharepoint-search-queries-explained.html) specifically this section: [Query Variables and Constants](http://www.techmikael.com/2014/05/s15e03-query-variables-constant-trouble.html) Better yet buy the ebook ["Search Queries Explained"](http://techmikael.blogspot.com/2015/01/sharepoint-search-queries-explainedthe.html) it is well worth the $10.

Comment: Wow, Thanks alot Matthew. There are alot to study. This is what I am looking for. Your answer priceless..:)

Comment: Can I get you to mark this as the answer? :)

Answer (score 0):

Follow the [Article](https://prasadpathak.wordpress.com/2013/08/09/sharepoint2013-avoid-default-results-in-search-result-and-content-search-web-part-with-search-box/)

Adding `\\{searchboxquery?}` to your Search Results Web Parts content source should work. If you are redirected to `osssearchresults.aspx` it sounds like you have changed the settings on the Search Box Web Part, make sure the setting; Send queries to other Web Parts on this page is checked, and your Search Result Web Part is marked as retriever.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Krumil. Infact I have solved my issue by looking at the article your have provided. But my question here is what is the significance of ? { \ in building query text. I need white paper or tutorial on this.